# Firefox extension offsetParent()

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, zepto

When calling offsetParent on a element in Firefox extension I get the following exception. This works fine in Chrome with no errors. I am calling it like this:

```
  $(passwordField).offsetParent();
```

[image]